# Angular trigger not working how need

Tags: jquery, angularjs, select, triggers, bind

I need customize 
items load from

```
$http(.....).success(function(data){
$scope.items=data
....
dothis() // my func
```

dothis() - https://jsfiddle.net/4ye83zte/4/

But i have error on `$(this).trigger('change');` (46 line number)

```
Error: $digest already in progress
```

I try:

```
angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('change') - have error too
```

But not working

Comment: I would suggest you to refactor the code a bit and adapt to angularjs more.

Comment: As @z.a. said clean up code first, but you can try with `$scope.applyAsync()` to avoid digest retrigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.$eval(function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    dothis(function () {
                        angular.element($('.pxyselect')).triggerHandler('change');
                    }, 0);
                });
            });
```

This worked after render element and after $digest